# Perl flattening arrays from hash results in ARRAY

Tags: arrays, perl

I'm trying to flatten an array contained in a hash with the following:

```
foreach my $key (keys %months) {
    foreach (%months->{$key}) {
       %months->{$key} = $key . ' ' . join(',', %months->{$key});
    }
}
```

I'm trying to generate a string of days like like:

```
"2, 11, 15, 18, 25"
```

But I get:

```
ARRAY(0x5a2e7b0)
```

Structure of `%months` is:

```
months {
    Jan: [1,5,30],
    Feb: [2,6]
}
```

Comment: The "_an array contained in a hash_" must be an array _reference_, and you never dereference. This would be the array: `@{%months->{$key}}` (assuming that it's the arrayref there indeed), where `%months->{$key}` retrieves the arrayref, and `@{ ... }` dereferences it. To generate your desired output you can then do `join ', ', @{%months->{$key}`, for instance

Comment: @zdim thank you, that fixed my issue.

Comment: Oh, I didn't see this comment until now.  I hope that an answer is still useful, in particular given the hashref's sigil comment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An "*array contained in a hash*" must be an array *reference*, a scalar (what a hash value must be).

Thus when you retrieve it you need to dereference it

```
my @ary = @{ $months->{$key} };
```

and you can generate the desired string out of it

```
my $date_list = join ', ', @{ $months->{$key} };
```

This assumes that `$months` is a *hashref*, judged by the arrow-dereferencing from the question.Then `%` in front of `months` is wrong. There is also an extra loop.  For the shown data

```
foreach my $key (keys %$months) {
    say join ', ', $key, @{$months->$key}};
}
```

or

```
say join ', ', $_, @{$months->$_}}  for keys %$months;
```

---

The code in the question applies to data with yet another level of nesting

```
foreach my $key (keys %$months) {
    foreach ($months->{$key}) {
       say join ', ', @{$months->{$key}->{$_}};
    }
}
```

to join only the last-level arrayref data, or

```
   say join ', ', $key, $_, @{$months->{$key}->{$_}};
```

to join both keys and the arrayref data.

Comment: @stevieb  Thank you, changed, for consistency.